# Expand parameter pack for a function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a function template as below. The template argument needs to be explicitly given.

```
template<typename T>
void Func() {...};
```

I need to call this function for each type in a parameter pack:

```
template<typename... Inputs>
struct SetStruct{
  void Set() {
    // Call Func() here
  }
};
```

Is there an easy way to expand the parameter pack? I tried:

```
Func<Inputs>()...;
```

and

```
Func<Inputs>...();
```

But none of them works.

I can only use C++11 :(

Comment: OP doesn't specify C++11, other question was a C++11 question, not a duplicate.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Variadic template param packs imply c++11 as a minimum.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont see:-(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Now it is a duplicate, it wasn't before.  Tags matter.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont My guts matter a lot :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to expand the parameter pack? I tried:
>
> `Func<Inputs>()...;`

If you can use C++17, using the comma operator and template-folding

```
((void)Func<Inputs>(), ...);
```

In C++11/C++14, using again the comma operator but in the context of initialization of an unused C-style array, something as follows

```
template<typename... Inputs>
struct SetStruct{
  void Set() {
    using unused = int[];

    (void)unused { 0, ((void)Func<Inputs>(), 0)... };
  }
};
```

Observe that, in both cases, I've added a `(void)` before the call to `Func<>()`.

In your case it's useless (because your `Func<>()` just return `void`) but it's a sort of security belt in case of a function that return an object of a class that redefine the comma operator.